# Jquery Extract URL from Text

Tags: jquery, url, extract

I need to extract URL from a text using jquery.

Lets say i have sowhere on the page following textarea code

```
<textarea rows="20" name="textarea" style="width:100%;">
   @techreport{blabl,  
   blabla = {},  
   url = {http://server.com/thepdf.pdf},  
   wrongurl ={http://server.com/thepdf2.pdf}, 
   blablabla = 1998,  
   blablablabla= {blablablablabla}}
</textarea>
```

i need the url, and only the url contents - not wrongurl.

Update: it has always the same structure and i only need to extract it ONCE and it always has an "url = {" in front of it.

Comment: So what exactly distinguishes url from wrongurl?

Comment: @Pekka: If I had a bet, I would say he is after the correct regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#click').click(function(){

 var one = document.getElementById('one');       
    one.value.match(/url ={([^}]*)}/,"");
    alert( RegExp.$1);


    })    
})
```

or a runnable demo
http://jsfiddle.net/PePS7/10/

oops, bit late to the game but ammended the example and the jsfiddle to only show the url

Comment: Good, but he only wants the url, not the "= {" and all that stuff. Apply my regex to your code and I think we have a winner.

Comment: great, its almost what i wanted, except it also gets me the url = {

Comment: @acidrat, sorry about missing that part, I ammended the example (granted you already got there!)

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to do some Reg ex on this.  If I was better at them I'd write one up for you.

Comment: do i really need regex if i know that my url always has "url = {" in front?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery won't do this, you're looking for a regular expression to extract the URL from the 'url' property in this textarea. You can do this with the following regex:

`/url = \{(.+)\}/.exec(textarea_str)[1]`

Comment: This wont work, javascript ignores the line jumps (If there's any) so it will select everything starting in the { after url until the final }

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is to use a regexp, like everyone has pointed to.

```
/url = \{([^}]*)\}/
```

That regexp should do it.